# How to Place the image at specific location of the Picture Conrol in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui, win32-process

I m trying to overlay an image on a live video.The IDE used is Visual Studio Professional 2010. The code is developed in C++.When I try to overlay image on the live video,  I m loading the image using a handle i.e.

```
                           HANDLE hBitmap;            

         hBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\BMP_Image.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP, 0,0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );
```

I am using the mechanism of Alpha Blending to overlay the image on to the video. Problem I have encountered is, The image is overlayed five consecutive times on to the video .

I m passing the ID of a picture control, placed on the dialog box in the rc file, to load the live video and display it. I m not using any MFCs in the code. The video is rendered by using Direct 2D mechanism

The video resolution is 640*480 and bitmap image resolution is 128*128. If I take this bitmap , the video will produce five times of  overlayed image on to the video..

I got the coordinates of dialog box using GetWindowRect() and ScreentoClient(). But I want the coordinates of the Picture control.

I have following doubts:

How to get the coordinates of the picture control???

How to place the image at specific location in a picture control???

Looking forward for ur positive response as earliest...

---

Regards,

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function for retreiving the handle of your picture control:

```
::GetDlgItem( hWnd of your dialog, Id of your picture control)
```

By retreiving its handle, you can get to other info like its position, size and

```
::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc)
```

If you overlay the image through some API calls such as StretchBlt, you can place it anywhere you want.